# Avoid null checks for setters Java

Tags: java, java-8, getter-setter

I have Employee class and I am setting its properties,

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
if (id != null)
    emp.setId(id);
if (name != null)
    emp.setName(name);
if (dept != null)
    emp.setDepartment(dept);
if (subDept != null)
    emp.setSubDepartment(subDept);
```

My question is, can we avoid null checks for each property setter?

I can not use ternary operator, as in that case setter would be called even if value is null. I want to avoid setter call if value is null.

```
emp.setName(name!=null?name:null);
```

Comment: How are you declaring the properties in the class? It is better to add it to the post

Comment: Use ternary operator into setters for null check

Comment: @MajedBadawi I am getting the properties from some methods

Comment: please check null at the time of setting in setter method if null then return from setter method the value will not be set so you didn't need to check every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, in your code, check null is not necessary: in every cases, since you just created the employee object, all his fields are null, then if, for example, `id` is not null the `setId` will set a not null value, if `id` is `null` then `setId` will not change anything.

Obviously, these considerations only make sense if the constructor does not initialize the variables shown in any way.

Comment: You don't know that without looking at what that constructor does. But you are almost certainly right.